# Problem with "endfloat" in manuscript option of APA6.cls

Tags: floats, packages, apa6

Several years ago I commonly wrote papers in MiKTeX using the `apa.cls`, which allowed you to switch between a two-column formatted "jou" mode and a single-column, double spaced "man" mode.

I have recently tried running these old `.tex` files in MiKTeX 2.9, and I have found that the `endfloat` package no longer works properly, either in `apa.cls` or the new `apa6.cls`.

I have tried renaming the `apaendfloat.cfg` file `endfloat.cfg` and placing it in the working directory.

Here are the errors I get with the `shortsample.tex` file that comes with `apa6.cls`. 
Basically, it completely chokes on the tables, and nothing comes out but gibberish in the table and figure portions of the paper.

Is there a solution for this?

```
AED endfloat: Processing end Figures and Tables [5]
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \@ef@tttopen 
l.83 \end{document}

?
 ! Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
<to be read again> 
                   \@ef@tttopen 
l.83 \end{document}

?
 ! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \@ef@tttopen 
l.83 \end{document}

?
 ! Undefined control sequence.
\processtables ...seout \efloat@postttt \ef@setct 
                                                  {ttt}{0} \clearpage \if@ta...
l.83 \end{document}

?
 [6]
! Undefined control sequence.
\processtables ...{ttt}{0} \clearpage \if@tabhead 
                                                  \section *{\tablesection }...
l.83 \end{document}

?
 ! Undefined control sequence.
\processtables ...@@spacing } \processtables@hook 
                                                  \@ifundefined {hrm}{}{\sf ...
l.83 \end{document}

?
 (R:\jointtex\SPRINT\apaexample.ttt
\begin{table*}[hbt]
\ifnextchar[{\eatarg}{}
! Undefined control sequence.
\table ...linechar `     \catcode `    =12 \ef@xtable 
                                                  \fi 
l.1 \begin{table}
                 [tbp]
?
 )
! Extra \fi.
\processtables ...ttt}\let \BBAB \normal@BBAB \fi 

l.83 \end{document}

?
 ! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \@ef@fffopen 
l.83 \end{document}

?
 ! Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
<to be read again> 
                   \@ef@fffopen 
l.83 \end{document}

?
 ! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \@ef@fffopen 
l.83 \end{document}

?
 ! Undefined control sequence.
\processfigures ...eout \efloat@postfff \ef@setct 
                                                  {fff}{0} \clearpage \if@fi...
l.83 \end{document}

?

/b/c4/cOverfull/b/c0/c \hbox (441.54912pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 1--83
[][]\T1//lmr//m//n//12 [tbp]
\caption{Some numbers that could be experimental data.
}
\label{tab:tab1}
\begin{tabular}{lcc}\hline
          & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Fa
ctor 2} \\ \cline{2- 
/b/c4/cOverfull/b/c0/c \hbox (1151.26506pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 1--83
\T1//lmr//m//n//12 3}
Factor 1  & Condition A  & Condition B   \\ \hline
First     
& 586 (231)    & 649 (255)     \\
          &    2.2       &    7.5        \\
S
econd    & 590 (195)    & 623 (231)     \\
          &    2.8       &    2.5   
     \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\efloatseparator
>0 
[7]
! Undefined control sequence.
\processfigures ...}{}{\sf } \processfigures@hook 
                                                  \@input {\jobname .fff} \fi 
l.83 \end{document}

?
 (R:\jointtex\SPRINT\apaexample.fff)
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\processdelayedfloats ...ocessotherdelayedfloats }

l.83 \end{document}

?

! LaTeX /b/c9/cError:/b/c0/c \begin{efloat@float} on input line 1 ended by \end{document}.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.83 \end{document}

?
```

Comment: I also received a bug report about the new version of the `endfloat` package today, it seems that this is my fault. I will examine this tomorrow. So far the best solution is IMHO reverting to endfloat.sty v2.4.

Answer (score 5):

As I just realized the `apa6` document class is redefining half of the `endfloat` package. (Some code was even simply copied from endfloat.sty and modified.) Since some internals needed to be changed from v2.4 to v2.5 of the `endfloat` package, these redefinitions are not working anymore.

I'm in contact with the maintainer of the `apa6` document class anyway, and we need to find a way to make it working again, and this time in a way where the `apa6` class is not using internals of the `endfloat` package so it won't break compatibility again if v2.6 of the `endfloat` package will be released.

I'll keep you informed, but until then one need to revert to the previous version of the endfloat package which was v2.4i, I'm sorry.

Addendum: Updating to version 2.5c of the `endfloat` package should help.

Comment: I was able to build a version 2.5c of the `endfloat` package which emulates most of the obsolete internal stuff needed by apa(6), so it should at least work again with the `apa` and `apa6` document classes, but only without using one of the new features added to 2.5. (The package looks now really ugly inside and is even more hard to change in future, but hey, this is not a coding beauty contest.) This version is currently under revision by the maintainer of `apa6`. If you are in urgent need for this version just drop me an e-mail.

Comment: It's available on CTAN, and as TeXlive update. (Don't know about MikTeX or other TeX distributions.)