# Table does not show up using \documentclass[man]{apa6}

Tags: tables, apa6, threeparttable

I use `\documentclass[man]{apa6}` and my table will not show up when compiling the `.tex`. I use the following code:

```
\documentclass[man]{apa6}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{relsize} 
\usepackage{apacite} 
\usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \begin{threeparttable}
     \label{table}
        \begin{tabular}{l c c c c} \hline
        & $i = 1$ & $i = 2$ & $i = 3$ & $i = 4$ \\ \hline
        $\pi_{0(i)}$ & 1.00 & 1.00 & 1.00 & 1.00 \\
        $\pi_{1(i)}$ & 0.90 & 0.80 & 0.70 & 0.60 \\
        $\pi_{2(i)}$ & 0.50 & 0.40 & 0.30 & 0.20 \\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Your problem is not reproducible. I am seeing the table in my PDF but I get an `Undefined control sequence. \efloatseparator` error. Please reduce your code to the very minimum.

Answer (score 1):

I get no error if I add the proper parts before the table.

```
\documentclass[man]{apa6}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{relsize} 
\usepackage{apacite} 
\usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % for mock text

\begin{document}
\title{X}\shorttitle{X}
\author{Who}
\affiliation{Z}
\abstract{ABS}
\maketitle

\kant[1-3]

\begin{table}
\begin{threeparttable}
     \label{table}
        \begin{tabular}{l c c c c} \hline
        & $i = 1$ & $i = 2$ & $i = 3$ & $i = 4$ \\ \hline
        $\pi_{0(i)}$ & 1.00 & 1.00 & 1.00 & 1.00 \\
        $\pi_{1(i)}$ & 0.90 & 0.80 & 0.70 & 0.60 \\
        $\pi_{2(i)}$ & 0.50 & 0.40 & 0.30 & 0.20 \\
        \end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\kant[4-6]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `apa6` documentclass with the option `man`, you should probably also use the option `floatsintext`. Citing from the user guide:

> When revising and proofreading a manuscript, it is most helpful to have the tables
>   and figures readily available (rather than turning most of the way to the end
>   floatsintext of the manuscript to access them). The `floatsintext` option (specified in the
>   `\documentclass` line) will integrate tables and figures approximately where they
>   are mentioned in the text. This is available only with the `man` option, of course,
>   because the other formats already have floats integrated with the text.

Since the table has a lot of "mathy" elements, I think it's more straightforward to input it as an `array` environment. You may also want to  organize the table's header a bit more; a specific suggestion for doing so is given in the code below.

[image]

```
\documentclass[man,floatsintext]{apa6}
%% Commented out the unneeded instructions
%\usepackage{enumitem}
%\usepackage{amsmath} 
%\usepackage{relsize} 
%\usepackage{apacite} 
%\usepackage{multirow} 
%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{bm}
%\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\title{xx}
\shorttitle{x}
\author{y}
\date{z}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \begin{threeparttable}
     \label{table}
     \centering
        $\begin{array}{@{} l c c c c @{}} 
        \toprule
        & \multicolumn{4}{c@{}}{i}\\
        \cmidrule(l){2-5}
        & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ \midrule
        \pi_{0(i)} & 1.00 & 1.00 & 1.00 & 1.00 \\
        \pi_{1(i)} & 0.90 & 0.80 & 0.70 & 0.60 \\
        \pi_{2(i)} & 0.50 & 0.40 & 0.30 & 0.20 \\
        \bottomrule
        \end{array}$
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would type that table:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[man]{apa6}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\begin{document}    
\begin{table}
    \begin{threeparttable}
        \caption{a caption}\label{table}
        \begin{tabular}{l *{4}{S[table-format=1.2]}} 
            \toprule
                         & {$i = 1$} & {$i = 2$} & {$i = 3$} & {$i = 4$} \\ 
            \midrule
            $\pi_{0(i)}$ & 1.00      & 1.00      & 1.00      & 1.00 \\
            $\pi_{1(i)}$ & 0.90      & 0.80      & 0.70      & 0.60 \\
            $\pi_{2(i)}$ & 0.50      & 0.40      & 0.30      & 0.20 \\ 
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        \begin{tablenotes}
            \item[*] an item
        \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, this results in the error `Undefined control sequence. \efloatseparator`. This depends on several redefinitions to the `endfloat` package which gets loaded by `apa6`. Please see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39053) for the status quo.